# How can I bring an application to the front with a batch script in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

Like if it's not open, start the application, otherwise bring the application to the front.

I already have this script, but I need it to bring it to the front:

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq TOTALCMD.exe" | find /i "TOTALCMD.exe"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 start "" "C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557166/bring-to-front-for-windows-xp-command-shell) on Stack Overflow you've got 3 options.

I **wouldn't use** the options of [CMDOW](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) or [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) from NirSoft because most virusscanners will trip over those utilities so you are left with 1 option:

I would use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

To bring a window to the front in AutoHotkey you could use its title:

```
WinRestore, Untitled - Notepad
WinActivate Untitled - Notepad
```

You could also follow the script on [this page](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/33659-if-program-is-not-running-then-start/) and code everything in AutoHotkey without the need for a batchfile. That way you could use the `.exe`-filename.

---

**But** if this is to code `TOTALCMD.exe` to only run once...
**It does have an option to only allow 1 copy at a time**

When selected if you run a second copy the first will become active.

[image]